# NSwagStudio add custom typescript imports/lines

Tags: typescript, nswag, nswagstudio

In my project I'm generating typescript clients via NSwagStudio.

To add credentails I have a BaseClient class that implements `transformOptions`.

```js
export class MyClient extends BaseClient{...
```

Now I need to add following lines at the beginning of each generated script:

```js
// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
// @ts-nocheck
import { BaseClient } from 'my-components-lib';
```

Can this be done via NSwagStudio-Configuration and if, how?

Answer (score 3):

For the `openApiToTypeScriptClient` code generator you can configure the setting `extensionCode` setting to use an external template.

Here's how I use it

```
"extensionCode": "nswag.imports.ts"
```

And this is what my nswag.imports.ts file looks like

```
import BaseClient from './MyComponent.base';
```

The final NSwag generated code looks something like this

```
/* tslint:disable */
/* eslint-disable */
//----------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     Generated using the NSwag toolchain v13.10.8.0 (NJsonSchema v10.3.11.0 (Newtonsoft.Json v12.0.0.0)) (http://NSwag.org)
// </auto-generated>
//----------------------
// ReSharper disable InconsistentNaming
import BaseClient from './MyComponent.base';
import axios, { AxiosError, AxiosInstance, AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse, CancelToken } from 'axios';
```